# field_info_instances() returns an empty set in hook_uninstall but not in module file

Tags: 7, entities

Why would `field_info_instances()` return an empty set in `hook_uninstall()` when it returns the expected results in the main module file?

I've used the exact same code to delete the fields for a set of bundles in both the .install file and the main .module file:

```
  $bundles = array('property', 'open_house', 'agent', 'office');
  // Delete fields
  foreach ($bundles as $bundle) {
    $instances = field_info_instances('content', $bundle);
    if (!empty($instances)) {
      foreach ($instances as $instance) {
        dpm($instance);
        //field_delete_instance($instance);
      }
    }
  }
```

The following code (pulled from `_field_info_collate_fields()` in field.info.inc) outputs the fields in a list:

```
  $definitions = array(
    'field_ids' => field_read_fields(array(), array('include_deleted' => 1)), 
    'instances' => field_read_instances(),
  );
```

as shown here:

```
 ... (Array, 2 elements)

     field_ids (Array, 149 elements)
     instances (Array, 8 elements)
```

It was suggested that I need to use `drupal_load()` and/or `drupal_load_include()` to load the field module or field.info.inc to use the `field_info_instances()` function. I also tried using `drupal_load()` to load my module, but the following code also does not work:

```
  $bundles = array('property', 'open_house', 'agent', 'office');
  drupal_load('module', 'field');
  module_load_include('inc', 'field.module', 'field.info');

  // Delete fields
  foreach ($bundles as $bundle) {
    $instances = field_info_instances('content', $bundle);
    dpm($instances);
    if (!empty($instances)) {
      foreach ($instances as $instance) {
        field_delete_instance($instance);
      }
    }
  }
```

Does anyone know why `field_info_instances()` would be unable to read the information about the field instances?

**UPDATE**:

When I run the following code: `dpm(field_read_instances(null, array('include_inactive' => TRUE)));` my fields are displayed.  Why are they inactive, is it because the module is being uninstalled and is disabled?  What should I do to work around this?

Comment: What are your field types? A field type module can't control its own fields, it gets really messy (this is why we split relation_endpoints off the main relation module for example).

Comment: Field types are text, image, address etc.  I'm just making instances of those.  I found out that this has been fixed in 7.8.  #943772 by jpsoto, yched, catch, bojanz, pillarsdotnet, steinmb: Fixed field_delete_field() and others fail for inactive fields.  Thanks chx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this has been fixed in 7.8. [#943772](http://drupal.org/node/943772) by jpsoto, yched, catch, bojanz, pillarsdotnet, steinmb: Fixed field_delete_field() and others fail for inactive fields.